# What's a word for someone who puts others down for having different views on a topic?

Tags: vocabulary

I'm trying to think of a word for someone who thinks their views are better than other views and talks down to others who don't have the same views.

Comment: Can you please include details, context and research? http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/5459/new-close-reason-include-the-research

Answer (score 5):

I'd be inclined to go for [Condescending](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/condescending) on that one:

> Having or showing an attitude of patronizing superiority

This usually includes talking down to people who don't echo the person's own views.

Comment: @Aishwarya A R: Thank you, though I really did like your suggestion of supercilious too.

Answer (score 4):

**Overbearing**

> unpleasantly overpowering.

**Autocratic**

> taking no account of other people's wishes or opinions; domineering.

**Snob**

> 1. a person with an exaggerated respect for high social position or wealth who seeks to associate with social superiors and looks down on those regarded as socially inferior.
> 2. a person who believes that their tastes in a particular area are superior to those of other people.

**Domineer**

> assert one's will over another in an arrogant way.

**Assumptive**

> arrogant or presumptuous.

**Supercilious**

> behaving or looking as though one thinks one is superior to others.

Source: Oxford Dictionaries

Answer (score 4):

*[Patronizing](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english-thesaurus/patronizing?searchDictCode=english)* could work, especially if the put down is a mockery of kindness:

> *[patronize](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/patronize)*:
>
> verb
>
> [WITH OBJECT]
>   1 (often as adjective patronizing) Treat with an
>   apparent kindness which betrays a feeling of superiority:
>   <sub>ODO</sub>

From *[This Tremendous Lover](https://books.google.com/books?id=en-WAgAAQBAJ&pg=PT230&dq=%22patronizing%20person%22%20conversation&hl=en&sa=X&ei=wD2GVYicDI7gsASBjIDgDw&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22patronizing%20person%22%20conversation&f=false)*, by Dom Eugene Boylan:

> Some men are quite adroit in turning the conversation to topics in which they can display their knowledge or ability. The ***patronizing*** person is generally a proud person, as also are those given to airs of superiority, to studied phrases or to a magisterial tone.
>   ***Emphasis*** added

Answer (score 2):

The informal *[snoot](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/snoot)* is a picturesque description of a person who "looks down their nose" at others:

> noun
>
> 1 informal A person’s nose:
>   *a sexist remark that might warrant a good smack in the snoot*
>
> 2 informal ***A person who shows contempt*** for those considered to be of a lower social class:
>   *the snoots complain that the paper has lowered its standards*
>   <sub>*ODO **Emphasis** added*</sub>

Answer (score 1):

I would call them **"presumptuous"** or **"pretentious"**.

> - presumptuous (adj) - too confident especially in a way that is rude : done or made without permission, right, or good reason. [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/presumptuous) -- characterized by or showing presumption or readiness to presume; unwarrantedly or impertinently bold; forward. [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/presumptuous)
>
> e.g. "It's a little presumptuous of you to assume you are the best lay I've ever had."
>
> - pretentious (adj)  having or showing the unpleasant quality of people who want to be regarded as more impressive, successful, or important than they really are. [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pretentious)
>
> e.g. "He is always making pretentious remarks about his education, how he graduated from Harvard, Magna Cum Laude, etc."

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is "contemptuous":  manifesting, feeling, or expressing deep hatred or disapproval; feeling or showing contempt.

Comment: For this to be a good and useful answer, you should cite a source, like an online dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of good suggestions here already.

Another option is "disdainful": full of or expressing contempt for someone or something regarded as unworthy or inferior
See https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disdainful